# Graph search algorithm where edges can be blocked by obstacles

Tags: algorithm, search, graph, path, shortest

I want to find a low-cost path between two vertices on a directed graph where the cost of each edge is the same. Ease of implementing the algorithm and performance time are very important, so I am willing to sacrifice an optimal solution for one that is near-optimal, if the algorithm is simpler and quicker.

An edge can be blocked by an obstacle. The probability that an edge is blocked is known beforehand. Blockages are independent of each other. An edge is found to be unblocked or blocked when the vertex at the head of the edge is reached.

My problem is similar to the Canadian Traveller Problem, but my understanding is that solutions for stochastic programming problems are relatively difficult to implement, and the time taken to find an optimal policy can be relatively high.

At the moment, I am thinking of converting the problem into a deterministic one so that it can be solved using a search algorithm like A*. Is this a good approach, and if so, how can I do this?

Comment: What's the difference between a "blocked edge" and no edge?

Comment: @angelatlarge Probability. No edge == blocked edge with 100% certainty

Comment: I was thinking of an edge being blocked by an obstacle (which I have now added to the wording) and making the edge untraversable, which I think is similar to saying there is no edge.

Comment: Could you just use one of the known shortest-path algorithms (Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, Johnson, Floyd-Warshall) and add a check before processing an edge that decides based on the probability whether the edge is blocked? After the edge is first encountered, you'll have decided whether it's viable and could store that information in the edge, no?

Comment: I was hoping to use an efficient search algorithm, possibly using heuristics, like A* search. The well-known shortest path algorithms like Dijkstra's Algorithm may not be efficient enough for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a partially observable Markov decision process (POMDP). POMDPs can be solved deterministically, but usually use a randomized algorithm to find an approximately-optimal solution. Finding the true optimum policy does not have a polynomial time solution, and even approximate solutions can be slow. On the upside, once you've found the policy, following it is fast.

Some of the available solvers:

- [ZMDP](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~trey/zmdp/)
- [Symbolic Perseus](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~ppoupart/software.html)
- [APPL](http://bigbird.comp.nus.edu.sg/pmwiki/farm/appl/)
- [pomdp-solve](http://www.cassandra.org/pomdp/code/index.shtml)
- [SPUDD](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~jhoey/research/spudd/)

Comment: This is a possible solution for me, but if approximate solutions can still be slow, I am concerned that this may not be efficient enough for my purpose.